# How to get altered tree from Immutable tree, maximising reuse of nodes

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js, immutable-collections

I have a tree structure data like this:

```
[{
    id: 54,
    name:123,
    children: [{
        id: 54,
        name:123,
        children: [{
            id: 154,
            name:1234,
            children []...
        }]
    }]
}, {
 ...
}]
```

I am using Angular 2. As far as I know, change detection kicks in whenever input changes and your change detection strategy is [`onPush`](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html).

To optimise the tree structure updates (e.g. toggling a node at a nested level or changing any attributes of such a node), I used [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

How can **Immutable** help me to optimise my updates? I read that **Immutable** reuses references from old data to construct new objects whenever data changes.

How do I use **Immutable** data structures efficiently to update nodes at a nested level?

#### Assumptions

1. I don't have a `keyPath` for any of the nodes.
2. Each node has a unique `id` property value which can be used to query tree data (but how?)

#### Problems

1. How can I update a node somewhere at a nested level? What could be the most efficient way of reaching out to that node?
2. How do I update multiple nodes? I heard of the `withMutations` API, but is there any other efficient way?

#### My approach

1. Deep-copy everything and then modify the newly constructed object:

   ```
   var newState = deepClone(oldState) // deep copy everything and construct a new object 
   newState.nodes.forEach(node => {
       if(node.id == 54) {
           node.id = 789;
       }
   })
   ```
2. What I am trying to implement:

   ```
   var newState = Immutable.fromJS(oldState) // create an immutable object 
   newState = newState.find(node => {
       node.set("id", 123);
   }); // any changes to object will return new object
   ```

With the second solution I hope to achieve re-use of nodes, as pictured below:

[image: Tree view in immutablejs]

Comment: "Immutable update" is an oxymoron. You have a value, and you want another similar value, so you create the differences and share the similarities

Comment: @Caleth agreed. But need your help in efficiently finding a way to reach node in a tree and update it

Comment: You create a *new tree*. Rather than copying unchanged values, you reference them, and this is safe because *nothing changes*

Comment: So is your data structure intended to be updated (mutable) or intended to be copied in its entirety with the change applied to the copy you make (immutable)? The latter is of course less efficient.

Comment: @trincot - I meant if my left part of the tree is updated I should be able to reuse the right part ?

Comment: Well, then please remove the reference to "immutable" in your question, because that is another concept, and not what you are looking for.

Comment: @trincot It is right?

Comment: Why do you ask that? Caleth already explained this. "Immutable" is not the same thing as "reusable".

Comment: Can you make your question more concrete. It is quite broad to ask *"How can I update a node at nth level.*". That depends on which criteria you have to find that node. Please provide concrete examples of what kind of queries/updates you want to do, and what you have tried.

Comment: *"If I make a tree data immutable and update only a part of it"*: this is ***impossible***. An immutable tree ***cannot*** have any part of it updated, by the definition of "immutable". You are just looking for updating a tree.

Comment: Provide example input, queries, expected outputs, and make very clear whether you are looking for a copy, made from the original tree, leaving the original untouched, or whether you want to update the original tree without making a copy. You have confusing messages in your question.

Comment: Added a image for more clarity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131350/discussion-between-display-name-and-trincot).

Comment: The image you posted illustrates that you misunderstand the concept of immutable. In fact, only in the first scenario (that of the copy), the tree could be immutable, while in the second (where you use the term immutable), it is certainly  *not* immutable.

Comment: Without code you have tried with, this question should be closed.

Comment: Added a code . Didn't understand reason for downvote. Agree that I might have wrong understanding of immutability but that's why I am seeking help

Comment: @trincot- Could you please help me?

Comment: @trincot could you please help?

Answer (score 10):

Realise that when you use Immutable for your tree structure, you cannot expect to replace a node without also changing the internal references to that node, which means that such a change will need to bubble up to the root of the tree, also changing the root.

More detailed: as soon as you use a method to change a certain property value, you will get a new object returned for that particular node. Then to re-inject that new node in your tree, i.e. in the parent's *children* list, you will use a method that will create a new *children* list (since the *children* property is immutable as well). Now the problem is to attach that *children* list to the parent, which will result in a new parent node, ...etc. You'll end up recreating all the ancestor nodes of the node you want to change, giving you a new tree instance, which will have some reuse of nodes that were not in the root-to-node path.

To re-use your image, you'll get something like this:

[image]

The Immutable API can do this for you with the [`updateIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/updateIn) method (or `setIn` if your update concerns only one property of the targeted node). You will need to pass it the key path to identify the (nested) node you want to modify.

So, if for instance you know the *id* of the node to be changed, you could use a little helper function to find the key path to that particular node.

```
function findKeyPathOf(tree, childrenKey, predicate) {
    var path;
    if (Immutable.List.isList(tree)) {
        tree.some(function (child, i) {
            path = findKeyPathOf(child, childrenKey, predicate);
            if (path) return path.unshift(i); // always returns truthy
        });
        return path;
    } 
    if (predicate(tree)) return [];
    path = findKeyPathOf(tree.get(childrenKey), childrenKey, predicate);
    if (path) return [childrenKey].concat(path);
}
```

You need to pass it the tree, the name of the property that has the children (so `children` in your case), and the function that will identify the node you are looking for. Let's say you want the path to the node with id 4, then you would call it like this:

```
var keyPath = findKeyPathOf(tree, 'children', node => node.get('id') == 4);
```

That key path could look something like this -- an alteration of an index in the array, and the `children` property providing the deeper array:

```
[0, 'children', 0, 'children', 1]
```

Then to modify the node at that path, you would do something like this:

```
var newTree = tree.updateIn(keyPath, node => node.set('name', 'Hello'));
```

Here is a demo with some sample data:

```js
// Function to get the path to a certain node in the tree
function findKeyPathOf(tree, childrenKey, predicate) {
    var path;
    if (Immutable.List.isList(tree))
        childrenKey = tree.findKey(child =>
            path = findKeyPathOf(child, childrenKey, predicate));
    else if (predicate(tree)) 
        return [];
    else
        path = findKeyPathOf(tree.get(childrenKey), childrenKey, predicate);
    return path && [childrenKey].concat(path);
}

// Function to compare two trees
function differences(tree1, tree2, childrenKey) {
    if (Immutable.List.isList(tree1)) {
        return tree1.reduce(function (diffs, child, i) {
            return diffs.concat(differences(child, tree2.get(i), childrenKey));
        }, []);
    }
    return (tree1 !== tree2 ? [tree1] : []) 
        .concat(differences(tree1.get(childrenKey), tree2.get(childrenKey),
                            childrenKey));
}

// Sample data
var tree = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Mike',
    children: [{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Helen',
        children: [{
            id: 3,
            name: 'John',
            children: []
        },{
            id: 4,
            name: 'Sarah',
            children: [{
                id: 5,
                name: 'Joy',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Jack',
    children: [{
        id: 7,
        name: 'Irene',
        children: []
    },{
        id: 8,
        name: 'Peter',
        children: []
    }]
}];

// Create immutable tree from above plain object:
var tree = Immutable.fromJS(tree);

// Use the function to find the node with id == 4:
var keyPath = findKeyPathOf(tree, 'children', node => node.get('id') == 4);

// Found it?
if (keyPath) {
    // Set 'name' to 'Hello' in that node:
    var newTree = tree.updateIn(keyPath, node => node.set('name', 'Hello'));
    // Print the new tree:
    console.log(newTree.toJS());
    // Compare all nodes to see which ones were altered:
    var altered = differences(tree, newTree, 'children').map(x => x.get('id'));
    console.log('IDs of nodes that were replaced: ', altered);
} else {
    console.log('Not found!');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help